# How to scale up and SVG from with in path instead of adding width and height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this icon in the following code , the problem with this icons is it has a big, margin all over, and in my case I want it to get that margin to be smaller, or the icon a litter bigger,  ,instead of increasing the general size as you will see the current implementation in the code.
any idea how to achieve this I tried some solutions but none has worked.

```js
import { ReactComponent as icon } from '../../Img/icon.svg';

// style 
const iconStyle = {
  padding: 0,
  marginTop: -5,
  backgroundColor: '#ef6c00',
  fill: 'white',
};

// inside the component
<icon style={iconStyle} width='24' height='24' />
```

Comment: Assuming the icon.svg has a viewBox on its root element, adjust the viewBox values.

Comment: @RobertLongson it has but it cut side of the icon

Comment: @RobertLongson any way to scale up with in the viewBox

Comment: Yes, change the viewBox values per my first comment. As you've not provided the markup for icon.svg it's hard to comment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open your svg into your editor and edit the svg tag directly.
for example here is the circle svg :

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />  
</svg>
```